# ggplot error bar legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am having difficulties adding a legend to my error bar plot. I tried several command that I've seen in other subject, but unfortunately it doesn't work (I am sure I'm missing something but I can't figure out what)

```
library(ggplot2)

errors=matrix(c(-3.800904,-3.803444,-3.805985,-3.731204,-3.743969,
  -3.756735,-3.742510,-3.764961,-3.787413,-3.731204,-3.743969,-3.756735,
  -3.711420,-3.721589,-3.731758,-3.731204,-3.743969,-3.756735,-3.636346,
  -3.675159,-3.713971,-3.731204,-3.743969,-3.756735),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)

modelName=c("model 1","model 2","model 3","model 0")
boxdata=data.frame(errors,modelName)
colnames(boxdata)=c("icp","pred","icm","icp_obs","obs","icm_obs","model")

qplot(boxdata$model,boxdata$pred,
     main = paste("confidance level 95% for age ", age_bp + start_age - 1,sep="")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=boxdata$model, ymin=boxdata$icm, ymax=boxdata$icp), width=0.20,col='deepskyblue') +
  geom_point(aes(x=boxdata$model,y=boxdata$obs),shape=4,col="orange") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=boxdata$model, ymin=boxdata$icm_obs, ymax=boxdata$icp_obs), width=0.20,col='red') +
  scale_shape_manual(name="legend", values=c(19,4)) +
  scale_color_manual(name="legend", values = c("black","orange")) +
  xlab("models") + 
  ylab("confidence level")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: You need to map color to a variable in order to get a legend.

Comment: Don't use `$` inside `aes`.

Comment: Bravo for making a figure which explains what the error bars mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using wide form data rather than long form data. You need to convert the data from wide to long before plotting if you want to get a legend.

```
library(ggplot2)
errors=matrix(c(-3.800904,-3.803444,-3.805985,-3.731204,-3.743969,
                -3.756735,-3.742510,-3.764961,-3.787413,-3.731204,-3.743969,-3.756735,
                -3.711420,-3.721589,-3.731758,-3.731204,-3.743969,-3.756735,-3.636346,
                -3.675159,-3.713971,-3.731204,-3.743969,-3.756735),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)

errors = rbind(errors[, 1:3], errors[,4:6]) # manually reshaping the data
modelName=c("model 1","model 2","model 3","model 0")
type = rep(c("model", "obs"), each = 4)

boxdata=data.frame(errors,modelName, type)

colnames(boxdata)=c("icp","pred","icm","model", "type")

ggplot(boxdata, aes(x = model, y = pred, ymax = icp, ymin = icm, 
                    group = type, colour = type, shape = type)) +
  geom_errorbar(width=0.20) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 4)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","orange")) +
  xlab("models") + 
  ylab("confidence level")
```

The output looks closer to your output can be generated by:

```
ggplot(boxdata, aes(x = model, y = pred, ymax = icp, ymin = icm, 
                    group = type, colour = type, shape = type)) +
  geom_errorbar(width=0.20) +
  geom_point(colour =  rep(c("black","orange"), each = 4)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 4)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("deepskyblue", "red")) +
  xlab("models") + 
  ylab("confidence level")
```